# Is there a shortcut on Android Studio to convert a text to uppercase?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to find a command on Android Studio to convert a selected text to uppercase but I'm unable to do so.

Is there any shortcut for this? I think it is a very common action on IDE but haven't found any clue yet.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

Select the text, then go to Edit → Toggle Case (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Windows).

[image]

Comment: That works, but is there a way to move to UPPER_WITH_UNDERSCORES from CamelCase ?

Comment: @vitriolix not natively, but there are plugins that can achieve this. I personally have used [this one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7160-camelcase/) and it worked great. It works better if you configure keyboard shortcuts for it IMO

Answer (score 103):

The IntelliJ shortcut is evidently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> on Mac) and should work since Android Studio is based off of it. [Here's their documentation page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/basic-editing.html).

Comment: Sure this doesn't work for you? Note that ctrl-shift+U is used for both Uppercase and Lowercase. So, e.g., first it will turn the text all lowercase and if you do c+s+u again, it will turn it all uppercase. It's not intuitive, but it worked fine on my Linux install.

Comment: There's a search function for IDE features that will help you find things like this and will also tell you the current keyboard shortcut. It's Help menu > Find Action.

Comment: +1 You're correct but for some reason ctrl + shift + U is not working for me. I realized this is the correct shortcut using @Saneesh CS answer's (the shortcut is showed on the menu). Thanks and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Yes this is working fine,  -> "ctlr+shift+u" , this will help if you want complete text either in capital or small letter.. ..

Comment: I have a windows and a mac. And i keep forgetting the mappings. Hence this helps . thanks

Answer (score 56):

You need to keep <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> on while using this shortcut.

I could not get the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to work in Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 until I turned on Caps Lock.

Comment: Why this racism for Ubuntu users? @Dhananjay you saved my day.

Comment: Does this still work? I removed the weird 'shelving' shortcut in Android Studio keyboard shortcuts cos it had the same mapping (CTRL + SHIFT + U), but it still doesn't work. It just activates some weird mode and converts the text to an underlined u. Edit: Have to use windows key as well as mentioned below

Comment: Are you still facing this issue @behelit?

Answer (score 25):

Sometimes some weird things happening. I am using `Ubuntu 18.10`.

My string is like :

[image]

Now when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then I am getting output like:

[image]

So I tried with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and its worked perfectly.

Note : I have kept <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> ON.

Thank you.

Comment: WHATS GOING ON, THIS IS SO ANNOYING

Answer (score 15):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> worked for me on my **Mac**

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 20.04 I had to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> with <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> OFF

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for it on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 , first turned on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/30169435/, posted over a year earlier.

Answer (score 2):

For **Ubuntu** users that ***Pratik Butani's*** answer work for them and it's still annoying to them, here is another workaround:

Go to `File > Settings... > Keymap`. Then search for the `Toggle Case` and there must be two results. Right click on one of them and then hit `Remove Ctrl+Shift+U`. Right click again and press `Add Keyboard Shortcut`. Then hold `Ctrl+Shift+Y` together and press `OK` button to change the shortcut. Finally click `Apply` to save changes.

Hope this **BUG** will be fixed soon...

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> works in Android Studio 1.5 on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+U should work on Windows.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).